# I Want to display a listview when i click a button in Monodroid. i tried this coding. its not running. Can anyone correct this

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to display a listview when I click a button in Monodroid. I tried the following code, however it doesn't run. Can anyone correct this?

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)

{

base.OnCreate (bundle);

SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btn);

button1.Click += delegate { listviewFunction(); };

}

public void listviewFunction()

{

 ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, _countries);

 ListView.TextFilterEnabled = true;

 ListView.ItemClick += (sender, args) => Toast.MakeText(Application, ((TextView) args.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
button1.Click += ...
```

Comment: oh Sorry... that's my mistake in this coding... but still i couldn't get the exact output..

Answer (score 0):

Declare a ListView globally:

```
private ListView _listView;
```

Now (1)create the ListView, OR (2)get it from a axml file:

(1)

```
_listView = new ListView(this);
```

(2)

```
_listView = (ListView)View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.MyList);
```

Now create your adapter, then:

```
_listView.SetAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Then create your ItemClick handler:

```
_listView.ItemClick += (sender, args) => Toast.MakeText(Application, ((TextView) args.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```